# How to implement single publisher and multiple subscribers asynchronous message system in C# using WCF and MSMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have searched a lot, but still I had few doubts about MSMQ implementation of WCF service.
Hence I have put this quetion.

I want to implement single publisher and multiple subscribers asynchronous message system.
I have decided to use WCF service as the publisher.
I have multiple instances of the window service on different machines as the multiple subscribers.

Q. I want to know that, how this model can be implemented as the old MSMQ approach?

The object of following type would be used in the message

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
public string Signal{get;set;}
public Guid Identifier{get;set;}
}
```

In the above class, Identifier would be used by the windows service to decide whether the message was published for that service or not.

Q. How the different window services will read the same queue?
Q. Where the queue should be hosted?
Q. Is it possible to send the acknowledgement from Window service(subscriber) to WCF service(publisher)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [this may be useful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your questions:

> I want to know that, how this model can be implemented as the old
>   MSMQ approach?

First off, MSMQ does not support publish subscribe out of the box.

> How the different window services will read the same queue?

So in publish subscribe, there in no ONE queue. Instead there are multiple queues, in fact one per participant in the pub sub scenario. So each publisher has a queue and each subscriber has a queue.

This configuration enables subscribers to send subscribe/unsubscribe messages to the publisher, and allows the publisher to send messages to the subscribers as necessary after evaluating the subscriptions.

> Where the queue should be hosted?

These queues can be hosted locally to each participant, or can be hosted together in some clustered location.

> Is it possible to send the acknowledgement from Window
>   service(subscriber) to WCF service(publisher)?

MSMQ does provide basic support for request/response messaging via [response-queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711345(v=vs.85).aspx) and [correlation-id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707132(v=vs.85).aspx) message header fields, though this is not truly out of the box (as you are required to consume and program against these values)

If you are not required to use WCF there is a fairly mature platform called [nservicebus](http://www.nservicebus.com) which sits on top of MSMQ and does provide support for all the messaging patterns you need.